Is the intention to do the assigned penance required for a valid confession?
To my knowledge, the things necessary for a valid confession are the following:

Verbal or interpreted (eg if one is mute) confession of at least all known mortal sins committed since one's last valid confession

The words ego te absolvo or the semantic equivalent said by the priest with the proper intention (presumed to be habitually held)

At least imperfect contrition (sorrow for sin on account of God's just punishments) and a firm purpose of amendment/intention to sin no more on the part of the penitent.


The priest assigns a penance to make satisfaction for the temporal debt due to sin, which does not have to be performed in order to receive absolution. So, for instance, if the penitent intends to perform the penance, but is distracted after leaving the confessional, and subsequently forgets to do his penance, his confession is still valid.
My question is whether that intention to do penance at the time of confession and absolution is necessary for sacramental validity, that is, whether one who positively intends not to do his penance is not forgiven, assuming all the other requirements outlined above are satisfied.
Please provide citations from a reputable Catholic source, such as a teaching ministry like Catholic Answers, Ascension Press, Word on Fire, or another, or official church documents if they are available.

I'd imagine if you used "..to do my penance..." in your formula for an act of contrition you'd "walk out of the confession with two sins", as the saying goes.  Does that factor into it?

@PeterTurner So you would lie and you would intend not to do penance, both sins, both potentially venial only. Though the lie may constitute the matter for mortal sin, because the lie is being told to the priest acting in persona Christi, such that the lying penitent lies to God (cf Acts 5:4). What if the penitent uses the first or third act of contrition recommended by the USCCB? These don't mention any intention to do penance. The third only implicitly expresses contrition, and makes no mention even of the firm purpose of amendment.

Oh, I think the second sin might be sacrilege.  That's what my kids catechism material says happens if intentionally don't confess some sins.  But I think we can assume, for this question, that the penitent did confess all his or her sins and did not verbaly lie during the confession?

@PeterTurner yes, we can, since some acts of contrition promulgated by our bishops don't say anything about doing penance.

@PeterTurner But doesn't the assigning of penance happen after absolution so the penitent would not know yet what would be the prescribed penance?  So what happens if the penitent confessed all his/her sins but is uncomfortable with the prescribed penance but not assertive enough to mention this to the confessor?

@GratefulDisciple I think this question is about intention.  It would seem that you should go into confession having the intention to do the penance required.  You actually can ask for another penance.   My wife did that once... once.

@PeterTurner Yes, in this scenario the intention is to do the penance.  Didn't know that we can asking the confessor for an alternate penance, which would resolve the issue that I have.

@GratefulDisciple I've always received my penance before even making my aft of contrition. My experience in the confessional is confession of sins > spiritual advice (optional) > assignment of penance > act of contrition > absolution

Whether a penitent is forgiven who does not have the intention to do penance:
Objection 1: It would seem that a penitent seeking reconciliation must be intent on doing whatever penance is given, lest he or she incur the penalty of sin for lying to the confessor.  The words ".. to do my penance ..." used in one of the ordinary Acts of Contrition approved by the USCCB, and the spirit of each must be the same since even words like ".. I firmly resolve to confess my sins ..."  are used in one, which is what just happened. It would be nonsensical to think that one Act of Contrition is not identical in spirit to the others, even if they don't have  words.  If a penitent knew that they had to make an act of contrition, which included a spiritual assent to do their penance, but did not share in that intention they would be guilty of deceit and their sins would not be forgiven.
Objection 2: The code of canon law states that the penitent is obliged to fulfill their penance:

Can. 981 The confessor is to impose salutary and suitable penances in accord with the quality and number of sins, taking into account the condition of the penitent. The penitent is obliged to fulfill these personally.

If someone knows they are obliged to do something and willfully does not, they are guilty of the sin of of the bummer son in Matthew 21:28-32.
Objection 3: If there is some impediment to the penance, or even if it is considered too lenient, the penitent can ask for a different penance

This is also why penitents can ask for a different penance!  If you don’t get what the confessor is talking about, or you think you cannot do something, ask for a different penance!
Fr. Z - https://wdtprs.com/2019/10/ask-father-am-i-still-forgiven-if-i-dont-to-my-assigned-penance/

The validity of the sacrament (in terms of contrition) certainly depends on the penitent's interior state so it makes sense the interior desire to do penance would also be there:

Thus, lack of at least imperfect contrition (fear of punishment) invalidates the absolution of the sacrament, as does lack of an integral confession (holding out sins which one is obliged to confess - mortal sins, in number and kind), and the deliberate intention not to do penance for one's sins.
https://www.ewtn.com/catholicism/library/sacrament-of-penance--common-issues-2709

And in cases where there simply was no penance given (because it was forgotten or the priest just doesn't do that for some odd reason):

From the point of view of the penitent I believe that there was no negative consequence. For the sacrament to be valid the penitent must accept the penance, that is, he must not refuse to accept it either openly or interiorly. Since this willingness is present in spite of the fact that the priest did not impose the penance, then the person is duly reconciled with God.
https://www.ewtn.com/catholicism/library/appropriate-penances-4438

tl;dr; yes

I see in the referenced EWTN article that it was written by someone with an STL. I'd like to know where that person found the doctrine that intention not to do penance invalidates the sacrament, but I will tentatively accept it on their authority, and because I trust EWTN as a reliable Catholic source.
